# how to get records from tempDB AX 2012 X++

Tags: batch-processing, microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to implement this functionality but vendBalanceProvisionalTmpProcesing is always empty, i know it is empty because it is tempDB :

```
 while select AccountNum,PostingProfile from vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing
            {
                select sum(AmountCur) from vendTrans
                    where vendTrans.AccountNum == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.AccountNum
                    && vendTrans.PostingProfile == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.PostingProfile
                    && vendTrans.TransDate >= _fromDate
                    && vendTrans.TransDate <= toDate;
            
                    tempSum += vendTrans.AmountCur;
            
                select sum(AmountMST) from vendTrans
                    where vendTrans.AccountNum == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.AccountNum
                    && vendTrans.PostingProfile == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.PostingProfile
                    && vendTrans.TransDate >= _fromDate
                    && vendTrans.TransDate <=toDate;
            
                    tempSum+= vendTrans.AmountMST*ledgerParameters.EonExchangeRate;
            
                    tmpValue.Amount = tempSum;
                    tmpValue.AccountNum = vendTrans.AccountNum;
                    tmpValue.PostingProfile = vendTrans.PostingProfile;
                    tmpValue.doInsert();    
            
            }
```

But there are 2 scenarios where i can access to vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.AccountNum :

```
insert_recordset tmpValue
        (AccountNum, PostingProfile, Amount)
        select AccountNum
        from vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing
            group by AccountNum
        join PostingProfile, sum(AmountMST) from vendTrans
            group by PostingProfile
            where vendTrans.AccountNum == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.AccountNum
                && vendTrans.PostingProfile == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.PostingProfile
                && vendTrans.TransDate < _fromDate;
```

```
    update_recordset vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing
        setting OpeningBalance = tmpValue.Amount
        join tmpValue
            where tmpValue.AccountNum == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.AccountNum
                && tmpValue.PostingProfile == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.PostingProfile;
```

Any way how i can do while select like that ?
`

I need vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.AccountNum to do two select sum over vendTrans where vendTrans.AccountNum == vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing.AccountNum. So way how to do it similar to these two scenarios where i have access to vendProvisionalBalanceTmpProcessing would help me.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to reread [on how to link to a temporary table](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/dynamics365/no-audience/2012/08/09/temporary-tables-ax-2012/). [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/temporary-tempdb-tables).

Especially, to access a tempDB table from outside where it is created, you need to call `linkPhysicalTableInstance`.